# Using jQuery Templates With Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, knockout.js

So far in the Knockout.js documentation, they only show using jQuery templates that are embedded within HTML script tags.  I was wondering if you could create jQuery [named templates](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/) and reference those instead?  Search that documentation for "named template" to see what I mean.

Comment: What do you mean by jQuery named templates? You could reference external templates.. RPN has an excellent blog post on that: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/using-external-jquery-template-files.html

Comment: @nEEbz The jQuery .tmpl documentation calls binding a string to a template named templating.  Just go to the documentation and do a find for "named template".  By doing what the link you've added says, you're still polluting the dom with additional script tags that seem completely unnecessary.  There has to be a way to do this with named templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KO 1.3 has the ability to provide your own template source. RPN has a post with a simple example of how you would provide templates as strings.

http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/10/ko-13-preview-part-3-template-sources.html